# Append to top and bottom of selected text in vim

Tags: vim

So I have the following text (==== delimiters denotes selected text):

```
This is some text
I'm not interested in.
    This is indented text
    not important.
    =====================
    This text portion is
    selected.
    =====================
    Also not important
    indented text
Other text i'm not
interested in.
```

Now I want to create a vim function so that when called, it appends at the top and at the bottom some default text. For example I would like to end with:

```
This is some text
I'm not interested in.
    This is indented text
    not important.
    THIS TEXT WAS APPENDED
    AFTER FUNCTION CALL
    This text portion is
    selected.
    THIS OTHER TEXT WAS
    APPENDED AFTER THE SAME
    FUNCTION CALL
    Also not important
    indented text
Other text i'm not
interested in.
```

Please note that indentation should be preserved (thanks benjifisher)
How can I do this?

Comment: If you know vim-latex suite, what I need is very similar to what you get when you press F5 (create new environment), but instead, in this case, I don't need to declare any environment (I always want the function to append some default text)

Comment: Tell me more about the indentation.  Do you want the effect of using `=` in Normal mode?  Do you want to copy the indentation from the first selected line?  Are all the selected lines indented the same way?  Do you have hard tabs or just spaces in your indent?

Comment: The perfect indentation solution would be:

Comment: *at top) indent should be equal to the first selected line
*at bottom) indent should be equal to the last selected line.

I don't understand the behavior of **=** in normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little sloppy, but it works:

```
function! Frame() range
  '<put!=\"THIS OTHER TEXT WAS\nAPPENDED AFTER\nFUNCTION CALL\"
  '>put=\"THIS OTHER TEXT WAS\nAPPENDED AFTER THE SAME\nFUNCTION CALL\"
endfun
```

Select your lines in Visual mode, and type

```
:'<,'>call Frame()
```

(The range `'<,'>` is inserted automatically.)  There are some advantages to using `:execute` with `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`as in `:help function-range-example`, instead of the Visual marks `'<` and `'>`, but that gets a little complicated.  You could also prefix each command with `:silent` if you do not care to be told that 3 lines have been added (twice).

Here is a version that copies the indentation from the first and last selected lines, as requested in the updated question.  This version uses `:call append()` instead of `:put`, which makes it more convenient to use `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`; possibly, this will be useful if you ever want to call the function with a range other than the Visual one.

```
" Add lines at the bottom before adding at the top, since the line numbers
" will change when you add lines.
function! Frame() range
  " Define a list of lines and prepend the desired indentation.
  let botlines = ['THIS OTHER TEXT WAS', 'APPENDED AFTER THE SAME', 'FUNCTION CALL']
  let botspaces = matchstr(getline(a:lastline), '\s*')
  let lines = []
  for line in botlines
    call add(lines, botspaces . line)
  endfor
  " Now add those lines at the bottom.
  call append(a:lastline, lines)
  " Now do the same thing at the top.
  let toplines = ['THIS OTHER TEXT WAS', 'APPENDED AFTER', 'FUNCTION CALL']
  let topspaces = matchstr(getline(a:firstline), '\s*')
  let lines = []
  for line in toplines
    call add(lines, topspaces . line)
  endfor
  call append(a:firstline - 1, lines)
endfun
```

Comment: This works, but a forgot to mention that I need to preserve indentation. I edited the question.